# Need a second help in understanding of theorem7.1 in chapter2 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not understand why $I - (I - K)^{-I}$ is of finite rank, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(y)$ be the matrix on the RHS of $(7.1)$.

$A$ is of finite rank !

We have, by $(7.1)$:

$(I-K)^{-1}y=y- \frac{1}{\det(a_{ij})}A(y)$,

hence

$I-(I-K)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(a_{ij})}A$.

Comment: yeah thank you so much :)